# Toggler button issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck at the navbar. I'm a (very) beginner so please try to explain it as laymanish as possible. The issue I encounter is that when I switch to a mobile-size screen the Toggler button is there (and it works as expected) however it's invisible. I (am trying to) use bootstrap 4.6 and this is what I've written so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

    <title>TBD</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Sample</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
        aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">A</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">Q</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">W</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">R</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help to get it visible is greatly appreciated.
[what I see at my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ6xl.jpg)

https://jsfiddle.net/t4f9jLzx/1/

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow family! One tip I would like to offer is that it's usually helpful to offer a running example of your code either through stackoverflow itself or a site like jsfiddle.net

Comment: could you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: never used it before, let me know if I got it right: https://jsfiddle.net/t4f9jLzx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `.navbar-dark` to nav tag and remove `.navbar-toggler-icon` class from `<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-icon"...`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Sample</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">Q</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">W</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">R</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```